# Designing application icons without Photoshop

Tags: icons, photoshop

Does anyone have any advice on creating application icons with a tool other than Photoshop? I want to create a few icons and am willing to invest some time in learning a tool but don't want to make a monthly payment for Photoshop or Illustrator - I wouldn't get enough usage out of it.

What other tools are there that are more affordable but can still create great icons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many alternatives to Photoshop. They all have the capacity to produce great icons, but the majority of the work is with the designer themselves rather than the tools. One popular (Free) alternative is [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org). It's interface is arguably more complex than Photoshop, but with a bit of learning you should get the hang of it pretty quick.